# Ext js get selected group records

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I use a groupping feature on my grid. How can I get all the records belonging to a single group when clicking on the group. I have searched the docs but haven't found anything useful..

PLease help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ext.data.Store` implement [`getGroups( [groupName] )`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getGroups) method. This method returns an array containing the result of applying grouping to the records in this store. If you pass in an optional groupName argument it will returns information about specific group.

In your listener for grid's `groupclick` event you can get records which belongs to group like this:

```
listeners: {
    groupclick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {

        // get array of records which belongs to clicked group
        var recordsInGroup = view.getStore().getGroups(group).children;
    }
}
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/391**